# Android: Opening a file from a folder I created withing interal memory

Tags: android, file, directory, internal

So I created a folder within internal storage, but how can I read from it later? I have methods for saving the file and reading it, however, I can't seem to find away to read from that specific location. Here's what I have so far. Thanks!

```
public void save(View v) throws IOException{
    File mydir = this.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
    File test = new File(mydir, "test.txt");
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(test); 
    String toSave = "huzzahs!";
    file.write(toSave.getBytes());
    file.close();
}

public void load(View v){
    try {

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("test.txt")));
        String stuff = inputReader.readLine();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stuff, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't find file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to match openFileInput() you should use getFilesDir() but you cannot create subdirectories therein.  If you want to use a subdirectory, pass the path or `File` and get an ordinary `FileInputStream` for that, rather than using openFileInput().

Comment: `that specific location`. You know what the location actually is? You realise that the directory is not called 'media' but 'app_media' and is NOT created by getDir() ?

Comment: It's true that "new File()" does not create a file on disk, but "new FileOutputStream(file)" does.

Comment: Yes, but not the dirs. You could add a mkdirs() to your answer as de OP forgot that too.

Comment: @Greenapps - actually getDir() is documented to create the directory if it does not already exist. It's good to have a critical eye for such concerns, but the actual problem here is a mismatch between the writing and reading locations - openFileInput() cannot use a custom location or a name containing a path separator, but only a filename within the exact directory matching the one given by getFilesDir().

Comment: Indeed getDir will create the subdir. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match openFileInput() you should use getFilesDir() but without creating subdirectories as openFileInput() cannot handle them.

If you want to use a subdirectory or other custom location, retain the path or `File` you are using and open your input stream by passing that to one one of the FileInputStream constructors:

```
new FileInputStream(path)
```

or

```
new FileInputStream(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, With a little more toying around, I seemed to have found my own answer. The below methods work perfectly.

```
File mydir = this.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

public void save(View v) throws IOException{
    File test = new File(mydir, "test.txt");
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(test); 
    String toSave = "huzzahs!";
    file.write(toSave.getBytes());
    file.close();
}

public void load(View v){
    try {
        File newFile = new File(mydir,"test.txt");
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile));
        String stuff = inputReader.readLine();
        inputReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't find file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Close, but you have one remaining problem.  It's not safe to call Context.getDir() on a Context object such as an Activity which has not yet been initialized to the point where its onCreate() method gets called.  So if you want to do it this way, you can keep the declaration of mydir where you have it, but move the assignment into onCreate() or otherwise assure it occurs no earlier.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks! This can't possibly be called before onCreate, to my knowledge. So that shouldn't be an issue.